# How to mix RTL and LTR text directions in the same <option> element?

Tags: html, css, localization, right-to-left, left-to-right

I am implementing a RTL interface. All components and texts are RTL but numbers which are LTR.

I use `<span dir="ltr">` elements to insert LTR texts into the main RTL texts.

It works in the most of the cases but not for a `<option>` element:

```
<div dir="rtl">
  <select>
    <option>One amount <span dir="ltr">15.000</span> coins</option>
    <option>Other amount <span dir="ltr">19،000</span> coins</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

It is not working.

Here there is a JSfiddle to play with: https://jsfiddle.net/fguillen/2hngzv3d/

Comment: Do you have to use `unicode-bidi: bidi-override;`?

Comment: @Aboodz you can try to remove it from the [JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fguillen/2hngzv3d/).. you will see that the `direction:rtl;` is ignored without it. Any how.. I don't think this is really relevant for the main problem I am exposing here.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

At the beginning, I thought it is a bug (something related to `unicode-bidi: bidi-override`), but when I tried on IE, Edge, and Firefox they all gave kinda the same result. This gave me enough evidence that this is a normal behavior. I Looked around here and there, and found what's wrong.

## The `<option>` tag

The `option` tag is somehow special. From Mozilla <[option](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/option)> documentation, it states that you can only write text inside it. This means any tag you write inside `<option>` tag, it will be ignored by the browser parser, and this is exactly why your`<span>` tag was ignored. See the image below from Firefox DOM inspector. It also worth mentioning that smartphones displays select option in a spinner instead of a combo box (of course you can override this). The means it is really meaningless to have any thing other than text within the `<option>` tag.

[image]

## Understanding `unicode-bidi` Attribute

RTL text, by default, is smart enough to handle embedded LTR text by applying the [Unicode Bi-directional Algorithm](https://www.w3.org/International/articles/inline-bidi-markup/uba-basics). If you override the algorithm by using bidi-override, you will be responsible for handling any LTR text within RTL text.

> This means that inside the element, reordering is strictly in sequence according to the direction property; the implicit part of the bidirectional algorithm is ignored. - (Mozilla Documentation)

Now in your case, you cannot place a `<span>` inside `<option>` because it is invalid  HTML nor use an `&LRM;` character because you disabled bidi algorithm.

## The Solution

The only solution I can think of is

- Step 1: Remove bidi-override.
- Step 2: Use RTL text instead of English text.

See this fiddler: https://jsfiddle.net/61dvmsnn/

## Moral of the story

Unless you are trying to create a mirror effect, never use bidi-override. Never disable bidi algorithm. Also, always use RTL text (e.g. Arabic, Hebrew, Farsi...) when testing inside RTL elements. Let the bidi algorithm works its magic.

Comment: Thanks for the extended explanation @Aboodz. Of course I am using RTL languages for the RTL interfaces, I just wanted to make the example simples maybe I screwed up. Removing the `unicode-bidi` manipulation did  the trick. Still I am gonna have the problem when I want to use LTR text that can not be detected by the unicode-bidi algorithm like: "What do you think about the firm CocaCola?"  where CocaCola must to remain LTR even in a RTL context.

Comment: It wont be a problem (see the link). Just make sure to use RTL question mark in the end of the sentence. https://jsfiddle.net/e6t5wwzo/

Answer (score 2):

you must use the `display:inline-block;` property like this:

```
<span style="display:inline-block !important; direction:ltr !important; text-align:left !important;">content</span>
```